# share data between two components (angular)

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where the user clicks a button to call the web service and pass the data to the 2nd component.
I looked through some examples but it is not working, if anyone would point out what went wrong it would be appreciated.

componentA:

```
callService(id: any) {
    this.xService.getInfo(id).subscribe({
    data => this.myData = data;
    this.xService.setData(data);
    });
}
```

componentB:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.xService.getData().subscribe(data => {this.myData = data; });
}

display() {
 console.log('test -- ' + myData.id);
}
```

service:

```
Injectable()
export class XService {

  myData: BehaviorSubject<MyData> = new BehaviorSubject<MyData>(undefined);
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}

  getInfo(id: string) {
        const param = new HttpParams()
        .set('id', Id);
        return this.httpclient.get<MyData>('/getxService', {params: param}).map(data => data);
  }

  getData(): Observable<MyData> {
        return this.myData.asObservable(); // <-- undefined from compB
  }

  setData(myData: MyData) {
      console.log('myData: ' + myData.id); // <-- this prints data (from compA)
      this.myData.next(myData);
  }
}
```

the `display()` is not printing ids but the `setData` under service printed actual ids.
I am thinking the issue might be that I cannot place ngOnInit for getData because componentA has not called yet so getData would be blank. I want to call getData when a display button gets clicked. If I placed getData under display it still wouldn't work...

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to pass the data through an Input in the second component?

Comment: yes because the templateUrl is tied to different htmls. componentA has different  html than componentB

Comment: That doesn't matter.  You can put component B inside component A's template e.g: component A.html: <component-b[myData]="componentAData"></component-b>.  You can add an ngIf that will only make component B visible when there is data.  Unless you are routing to a different page, in which case just fetch the info again.

Comment: Here is a good article that explains it: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Well first of all you are not calling `display()` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @AJT_82 display() is an output in html  <div> {{ display() }} </div>

Answer (score 1):

add this changes it will work:

```
Injectable()
export class XService {
    private data: any = {};
    myData$: BehaviorSubject<MyData> = new BehaviorSubject<MyData>(undefined);
    constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}

    getInfo(id: string) {
       const param = new HttpParams().set('id', Id);
       return this.httpclient.get<MyData>('/getxService', {params: param}).map(data => data);     
    }

    getData(): any {
       return this.data;
    }

   setData(myData: MyData) {
     this.data = myData;
     this.myData$.next(myData);
   }
}
```

In your B component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.xService.myData$.subscribe(data => {this.myData = data; });
    this.myData = this.xService.getData();
}

display() {
 console.log('test -- ' + myData.id);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the input but the data is still coming out as 'undefined' I use display() as an output in html    <div> {{ display() }} </div>

Comment: going to +1 this as I think my issue is related to checking the data before it arrives.